# There exists an element $x$ of $M$ such that $W^{-1}R\dfrac{x}{1}=W^{-1}Rz$ and $\operatorname{ann}_R x=\operatorname{ann}_{W^{-1}R} z\cap R$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, localization

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $W$ a multiplicative subset of $R$, $M$ an $R$-module, and $z$ an element of $W^{-1}M$. Show that there exists an element $x$ of $M$ so that $W^{-1}R\dfrac{x}{1}=W^{-1}Rz$ and $\operatorname{ann}_R x=\operatorname{ann}_{W^{-1}R} z\cap R$ (i.e. $Rx\hookrightarrow W^{-1}R\dfrac{x}{1}=W^{-1}Rz$).

For the first part: Let $z\in W^{-1}M$ and $x\in M$. Well then $\dfrac{x}{1}\in W^{-1}M$. Since $z$ is an arbitrary element of $W^{-1}M$ and $R$ is Noetherian then $W^{-1}R\dfrac{x}{1}=W^{-1}Rz$. Is this correct?

Also how do I begin the following part? I know that $\operatorname{ann}_R(M)=\{a\in R \ | \ aM=0\}$. But how do I use that when I have intersections?

Comment: 1) I found no meaning to your argument for the first part. 2) The element $x$ has to be found. In order to use that $R$ is Noetherian I suggest to consider the ideal $I=\mathrm{ann}_{W^{-1}R} z\cap R$ of $R$. Pick a finite system of generators for $I$ and use it to construct an appropriate $x$.

Comment: So I show prove the second item first to then apply it to the first item.

Comment: For the first claim it's easy to find such $x$. If $z=m/w$ then $x=m$ works. The second condition is the problem.

Comment: So how should I proceed?

Comment: Just do what I suggested you in the first comment.

Comment: Can't I just show that $\phi$ is injective where $\phi:Rx\hookrightarrow W^{-1}R\dfrac{x}{1}$?